# 'apktool' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file

Tags: android, cmd, path, reverse, apktool

i am trying to reverse engineer an apk for android studio project but i am stuck at this step. it says apktool is not recognized. i have created a folder in my c drive named Apktool and i have apktool.jar,apktool.bat,backsmali.jar and smali.jar in it. i have also tried setting my path locations various times but still there seems to be an issue. please help me out, also tell what is the correct path address i need to put, and if i can have various path addresses so my machine can automatically pick the right one or do i need to have just one correct path and class address. also what about the java home address ?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xuoKm.png)

Comment: use this to decompile apk https://github.com/skylot/jadx

Comment: how do i decode androidmanifest.xml ?